# need the work around with the mysql query

Tags: mysql

Folks

when i m running the below query , i m getting the error for invalid use of group by function

```
    SELECT `Margin`.`destination`, 
ROUND(sum(duration),2) as total_duration, 
sum(calls) as total_calls 
FROM `ilax`.`margins` AS `Margin` 
 WHERE `date1` = '2013-08-30' and `destination` like "af%"  
AND ROUND(sum(duration),2) like "3%"  
group by `destination` 
ORDER BY duration Asc LIMIT 0, 20;
```

let me know the work around

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated *before* grouping takes place, so `SUM()` cannot be used therein; use the `HAVING` clause instead, which is evaluated *after* grouping:

```
SELECT   destination,
         ROUND(SUM(duration), 2) AS total_duration,
         SUM(calls)              AS total_calls
FROM     ilax.margins
WHERE    date1 = '2013-08-30'
     AND destination LIKE 'af%'
GROUP BY destination
HAVING   total_duration LIKE '3%'
ORDER BY total_duration ASC
LIMIT    0, 20
```

Note also that one really ought to use numeric comparison operations for numeric values, rather than string pattern matching.  For example:

```
HAVING   total_duration >= 3000 AND total_duration < 4000
```